Configuring Nginx on WSL Ubuntu on Windows 11. Config errors
Im having some issues configuring a virtual host in nginx. I followed this tutorial.
How to Install Magento 2 on Ubuntu with Windows 10/11 WSL
My vhost code in sites available looks like this:
server { 
listen 80; 
localhost http://localhost.t3chn0.com; 
root /var/www/html/te3chn0.com/; 
index index.php; 
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
} 
location ~ \.php$ { 
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; 
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock; 
} 
location ~ /\.ht { 
    deny all; 
} 

}
that returns this error:
t3chn0@MikesYoga:/var/www/html$ sudo nginx -t nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "t3chn0" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/t3chn0.com:3 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

When I clone the default file I get this error instead.
t3chn0@MikesYoga:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo nginx -t nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:60 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Does anyone have any tips on what I might be doing wrong here? I'm new to Nginx. I could have figured this out in Apache.
Thanks in adavance

You have a typo in root directive.
It should be /var/www/html/t3chn0.com/ instead of /var/www/html/te3chn0.com/
